# Send custom response in gorilla mux when route method does not match

Tags: go, gorilla, mux

how can I send a custom response when the route method (HTTP Verb) does not match?

When I hit the following route in a post method

```
r.handleFunc("/destination", handler).Methods('GET')
```

I want to receive (let's assume its a JSON response)

```
{
    status: "ERROR",
    message: "Route method not supported."

}
```

The idea is that I don't want to have each handler with the **route.Method == $METHOD** check. Looking for a way where I can define once and apply to each route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup custom return for route methods, you could simply override the handler "MethodNotAllowedHandler" with your own.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router()))
}

func router() *mux.Router {

    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.HandleFunc("/destination", destination).Methods("GET")
    r.MethodNotAllowedHandler = MethodNotAllowedHandler()
    return r
}

func destination(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "destination output")
}

func MethodNotAllowedHandler() http.Handler {

    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Method not allowed")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out some the gorilla/handler repository. It contains middleware handlers (e.g. handlers that are executed before your main handler) including a [handler for checking whether a HTTP method is allowed](https://github.com/gorilla/handlers/blob/master/handlers.go#L28). E.g.:

```
MethodHandler{
  "GET": myHandler,
}
```

Any other method will automatically return a `405 Method not allowed` response.